# Time Based Scoring Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi I'm a beginner in unity and I want to be able to add 10 points to the score every 5 seconds since the game started, this is how i tried to implement it

```
private int score;
void Update () {

    Timer = Time.time;

    if (Timer > 5f) {

        score += 5;
        Timer -= 5f;
    }
    ScoreText.text = score.ToString ();

 }
```

this is not working what happens is the score increases rapidly after 5f and then it crashes my game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The math for calculating every 5 seconds is wrong. You should not be doing `Timer = Time.time;` every loop, that just throws away the old value of `Timer`. Use `Time.deltaTime` and add it to the timer instead.

```
 //Be sure to assign this a value in the designer.
 public Text ScoreText;

 private int timer;
 private int score;

 void Update () {

    timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (timer > 5f) {

        score += 5;

        //We only need to update the text if the score changed.
        ScoreText.text = score.ToString();

        //Reset the timer to 0.
        timer = 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: string not text on line 2

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a bit late to answer, but the same can be done with `Mathf.FloorToInt(Time.timeSinceLevelLoad)`